# Make element fall to bottom position

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make the red block fall to the bottom/ position bottom when there's no blue block under it. Right now when the blue block moves away, the red block just floats there.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner {
  margin-top: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: move 4s infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -350px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should it work only in this case, or also if the blue box animated differently? If you want to achieve something physics-like, you had better to try a library for that...

Comment: The gist is that, I'm trying to make it so that the red block would fall to the bottom when the blue block is moved away or changed in width 0 @FZs

Comment: Try adding `display: none;` under @keyframes's 100% block

Comment: _“when the blue block is moved away”_ - from the perspective of the layout flow algorithm, it never does. You are using relative positioning here to “move” the element - but one of the basic principles of that is, that it leaves the space the element would have taken _originally_, reserved.

Comment: I got that, my question is whether the solution may abuse the fact that it always takes the blue block the same time to get away, or may this timing change. The former version is easy to solve, the latter is pretty hard.

Answer (score 1):

The 'natural' way to do this might be to set `display: none` on the blue block as it animates out of view. Unfortunately CSS animations won't set display.

You can however animate height, and by giving the element just a split second when it transforms from height 50px to 0px you can make it look as though it has disappeared instantly.

This snippet is a bit rough - you'll need to make sure the %s in the animation are what you want.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner {
  margin-top: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: move 4s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  69.999% {
    height: 50px;
    }
  70% {
  left: -300px;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -350px;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate the `bottom` property of `.red`

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative; /* NEW */
  animation: move-down 4s infinite; /* NEW */
}

.blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: move 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

/* NEW */
@keyframes move-down {
  /* since move's duratin is 4s. */
  50% {
    bottom: 0
  }
  100% {
    /* since both rectangles have the same height. You need to move down only by 50%  */
    bottom: -50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to drop `.red` (No animation)

```
    @keyframes move-down {
      50% {
        bottom: 0
      }
      51% {
        bottom: -50%
      }
      100% {
        bottom: -50%
      }
    }
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative; /* NEW */
  animation: move-down 4s infinite; /* NEW */
}

.blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: move 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}


/* NEW */

@keyframes move-down {
  50% {
    bottom: 0
  }
  51% {
    bottom: -50%
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```